# Not searching the first letter

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, plist, uisearchbar

I am loading my plist into a TableView and it is going everything ok, but now when I search something it doesn't consider the first letter. Below you see the directory.plist and my Main.storyboard

[image: plist and storyboard]

To load the plist correctly I put the following code on my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```swift
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "directory", withExtension: "plist"), let array = NSArray(contentsOf: url) as? [[String:Any]] {
            Shared.instance.employees = array.map{Employee(dictionary: $0)}
        }
        return true
}
```

I also have a Structure helping me to load all my stuff:

```swift
struct EmployeeDetails {
    let functionary: String
    let imageFace: String
    let phone: String

    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.functionary = (dictionary["Functionary"] as? String) ?? ""
        self.imageFace = (dictionary["ImageFace"] as? String) ?? ""
        self.phone = (dictionary["Phone"] as? String) ?? ""
    }
}
struct Employee {
    let position: String
    let name: String
    let details: [EmployeeDetails] // [String:Any]

    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.position = (dictionary["Position"] as? String) ?? ""
        self.name = (dictionary["Name"] as? String) ?? ""
    
        let t = (dictionary["Details"] as? [Any]) ?? []
        self.details = t.map({EmployeeDetails(dictionary: $0 as! [String : Any])})
    }
}

struct Shared {
    static var instance = Shared()
    var employees: [Employee] = []
}
```

**Until here, everything is running well!** Now I became having trouble when I tried to insert a SearchView, take a look what I did until now:

```swift
class Page1: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    
    var employeesSearching = [Employee]()
    var isSearching : Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.searchBar.delegate = self
    }
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if self.isSearching == true {
            return self.employeesSearching.count
        } else {
            return Shared.instance.employees.count
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell1
        let employee = Shared.instance.employees[indexPath.row]
        
        if self.isSearching == true {
            cell.nameLabel.text = self.employeesSearching[indexPath.row].name
            cell.positionLabel.text = self.employeesSearching[indexPath.row].position
        } else {
            cell.nameLabel.text = employee.name
            cell.positionLabel.text = employee.position
        }
        return cell
    }
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if self.searchBar.text!.isEmpty {
            self.isSearching = false
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            self.isSearching = true
            self.employeesSearching.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            for i in 0..<Shared.instance.employees.count {
                let listItem : Employee = Shared.instance.employees[i]
                if listItem.name.range(of: self.searchBar.text!.lowercased()) != nil {
                    self.employeesSearching.append(listItem)
                }
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? Page2,
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            destination.newPage = Shared.instance.employees[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

I am having trouble on the first letter of my searches. Take a look:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
if listItem.name.range(of: self.searchBar.text!.lowercased()) != nil {
```

You are looking for the lowercase version of the search text in the regular text of the employee name.

The text "John Smith" does not contain the search text "j". But it does contain the search text "ohn".

The quick fix is to change that line of code to:

```
if listItem.name.lowercased().range(of: self.searchBar.text!.lowercased()) != nil {
```

This now compares the lowercase version of both the employee name and the search text. So now it will match since "john smith" contains "j".

BTW - it's inefficient to lowercase the search text over and over. And there's a better way to write the loop code. I would change it to:

```
self.employeesSearching.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
let searchText = self.searchBar.text!.lowercased()
for employee in Shared.instance.employees {
    if employee.name.lowercased().range(of: searchText) != nil {
        self.employeesSearching.append(employee)
    }
}
```

And even simpler approach is to replace that code with:

```
let searchText = self.searchBar.text!.lowercased()
self.employeesSearching = Shared.instance.employees.filter { $0.name.lowercased().range(of: searchText) != nil
}
```

To search the text in either the name or the position, simply update the comparison expression:

```
if employee.name.lowercased().range(of: searchText) != nil || employee.position.lowercased().range(of: searchText) != nil {
```

Make a similar change if you use the `filter`.

Comment: Great! It is done, now just for the knowledge. What should I change to search not only the `name` but also the `position`?

Comment: See my updated answer. This is some pretty basic stuff. I kindly urge you to spend time reading the "The Swift Programming Language" book from Apple. The more you understand the language, the better off you'll be.

Comment: I am about to do it, than you so much for the lessons!!

Comment: I just noticed that when I search for "Suzan" and then I touch on Suzan result, it shows the content of "John". Can you see anything wrong on my code?